# Paleo-magnetism for the solar system over millions of years from the widmanstatten pattern?

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment, geomagnetism

I understand that the widmanstatten pattern (long fingerlike crystalline structure of iron nickel meteorites) is due to a slow cooling and solidification of asteroids over tens of millions of years.

Given the ferromagnetic nature of the material and this long solidification period, it would appear to be an ideal scenario for the study of the sun's magnetic field over extreme long time scales.

While these fragments may have rotated and had eccentric orbits there exist enough fragments from enough different sources that we ought to be able to build an idea of our solar systems magnetic field over almost unimaginable time scales.

I haven't found any research along these lines, any comments on why this may or may not work?

**EDIT:**
Very recent relevant paper:
https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2021/08/210811100810.htm

Someone with experience in Earth's paleo-magnetism might be helpful, knowing whether the techniques used in terrestrial samples would work here. Such data would be invaluable to further our understanding of the solar system and models of the sun.

Comment: By the time the solar wind's magnetic field gets to Earth, it's incredibly messy (i.e., turbulent) and very small in magnitude (i.e., ~5-10 nT).  The field changes enough that only the most coarse-grained average might show up and even then, it would get washed out if the cooling time scale wasn't just right...

Comment: @honeste_vivere That is true; however, if you factor in the flux concentration via ferromagnetism we end up with a roughly three order of magnitude increase, bringing us back in realm of earths magnetic field strength. Still you are correct, this would be a challenge. We might not be able to find a signal from the Heliospheric current sheet (Parker spiral),  or sun pole reversal, but there might be signals of other events we're not even looking for, happening over much larger time scales. As a slight segway, would metallic bodies conduct the heliospheric current and leave a signature?